# UICollectionViewCell outlet frame change animation

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I have a UICollectionView which uses a waterfall style layout to show different sized cells. The height calculation for each cell works just fine.

The problem I have is that I have to change the size of two outlets (UIImage and UILabel) in each cell and I don´t know where to change the frame size in order prevent the UICollectionView from animating said frame size change. I tried it to do in the layoutSubviews method of each cell and in the cellForItemAtIndexPath without results. Every time the viewcontroller containing the UICollectionView appears the frame change for the two outlets in each cell is animated.

Example setting the frame for just the image inside cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CVCNewspaper *cell = (CVCNewspaper *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER_NEWSPAPER forIndexPath:indexPath];
BONewspaper *newspaper = [newspapers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGFloat width = cell.frame.size.width;

// Calculate rect for imageView
CGFloat objectWidth = newspaper.coverNews.imageWidth ? newspaper.coverNews.imageWidth : 180;
CGFloat objectHeight = newspaper.coverNews.imageHeight ? newspaper.coverNews.imageHeight : 100;
CGFloat scaledHeight = floorf(objectHeight / (objectWidth / width));

cell.imageViewCover.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINVIEW, HEADERHEIGHT + 5, width, scaledHeight);

[cell fillCellWithNewspaper:newspaper];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: If you assign your cell properties within your layout subclass, the viewcontroller should load them without animating. Are you subclassing flowlayout, using the flowLayoutDelegate, or a custom layout?

Comment: I use this customLayout https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout. But I can´t figure out how to pass the object which contains the size information to the layout before the cells get drawn. Where would I do that?

Also the cell itself is not getting animated, it has its correct size when the view appears, but the cells outlets are animated within the cell when the view appears.

Comment: Ok, so collectionViewLayouts give your collectionview all the cell data it needs to visually display your cells. Any changes you want done without animation should be done within the layout subclass. 
For this, in the CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout class, under the **-prepareLayout** method...
`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes =
        [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        
attributes.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, self.itemWidth, itemHeight);`
That's where you'll want to handle it. Neat project. Thanks for the link.

Comment: As I said before the cell itself is not the problem as it is displayed correctly (correct size without animation). The cell has 2 subviews that get animated when I change theirs frame size but the cell itself stays the same.

Comment: Yep. Moving the code into the layout class should fix that as well. If it doesn't, it could be a constraints issue with you cell. Hard to say without seeing the code.